Dynamically place files in different containers
Files are dumped into ADLS2 using XYZ_FileName.txt, ABC_FileName.txt format, where XYZ, ABC stands for different business units. Using ADF, I need to copy these files to their intended containers.
Used metadata to identify the txt files, used a forEach loop, inside forEach used a set variable and switch activity.
How to solve this?

Instead of switch activity, you can directly copy the files to their intended containers like below.
First take a Get meta data activity to list out the file names list and give that array @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems to the For-each activity expression.
Inside For-each take a copy activity with new source and target datasets.

Here, for demo I took Binary datasets, in your case if you are dealing only with .txt file, you can use delimited text dataset.
In the source dataset, give your source container name and in the file name use @item().name expression. Ignore the warning, it will give expected results during the pipeline debug run.

In the target dataset, give below expressions for the container name and file name.
container_name - @toLower(split(item().name,'_')[0])
file name - @item().name

Here, the storage account, does not support the container names to be in capital letters. So, use toLower() on the expression.

Now, debug the pipeline and the files from source will be copied to the intended containers. If the container exists with given name, it will copy the file to it and if not exists, then it will create one with given name and copied the file to the container.
Result files:

